# How to calulcate index pages scanned and relation pages scanned

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, b-tree

I have some homework problems that require that I calculate the total cost of queries. Some of the assumptions made for the queries are:

1. All costs are in terms of disk pages, cost of scanning the index, and cost of reading matching
   tuples from the relation if needed.
2. If reading tuples from a relation, use the worst case scenario: all tuples are in different disk
   pages.
3. Assume all indices have 3 levels (root, internal node, and leaf level), and the root of all indices
   are in memory so scanning the root incurs no cost. Most searches will have one node from
   the internal level and a number of leaf nodes.
4. Postgresql returns the size of an index in terms of the number of pages using the query below.
   For the B-tree index, assume the numbers provided are the number of leaf nodes.

My professor also gives us a sample query to get the cost for, but I don't know exactly how he got to these numbers. The database in question looks like:

```
create table series (
seriesid int primary key
, title varchar(400)
, yearreleased int
, contentrating varchar(40) -- age group the movie is intended for
, imdbrating float -- imdb rating
, rottentomatoes int -- rotten tomatoes rating
, description text
, seasons int -- how many seasons are available
, date_added date -- date series is added to Netflix
) ;
```

and the query the calculate the cost for looks like so:

```
qa: select director from seriesdirectors where seriesid <= 100;
```

The index referenced is seriesdirectors_pkey which has 2 relation pages, and the query returns 5 tuples in total.

Using these numbers my professor somehow got to the conclusion that the number of index pages scanned is 3 and the number of relation pages scanned is 0.

The reasoning being: "because there are 5 tuples matching this query (1 internal node, and 2 leaf nodes in the worst case), and the index contains all the necessary information (so zero tuples need to be read)." I have been trying to understand the concepts of index pages and how exactly my professor got these numbers so I can work on the rest of the problems. If any more context is needed and I will let you know.

Edit: The definition of the index page in this case is a way to store tuples from a database with a unique identifier (i.e. a standard index for a database, more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index).

The big question I have is how can I calculate the total number of index pages queried and the number of relation pages queried. The example query above (`qa`) was using the index seriesdirectors_pkey which has 2 relation pages and returns a result of 5 rows. I don't know how we get from that to knowing that 3 index pages were queried and 0 relation pages were queried.

Comment: Missing information: what is the index definition? Also, what is your question?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried to add the additional information in the post, please let me know if more context is needed

Comment: Wait a minute. You show the definition of `series`, but your query is on `seriesdirectors`. "The index referenced": referenced by what? If the index has 2 pages, it cannot have three levels. Somehow this is all confused.